# PHP: Two machines, different results with a simple PHP script

Tags: php, file, fopen

The problem: we have large code base which isn't working correctly. We have through the process of elimination figured the following few lines are causing the issue.

We have a small identical script on two machines (access key has been modified).

```
$url = "http://images.shrinktheweb.com/xino.php?stwsize=xlg&stwaccesskeyid=82322b94fs1c912&stwu=bfbf5&stwinside=1&stwurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.digitalartistshandbook.org%2Fnode%2F35";    
$lines = file($url);
print implode("", $lines);
```

**Machine 1:**

- This script works fine and prints the expected response.

**Machine 2 (the problem):**

- This script doesn't work and doesn't print anything to the terminal. It finishes with no errors in the php.log or on the terminal.

Now, with another script:

```
$url = "http://images.shrinktheweb.com/xino.php?stwsize=xlg&stwaccesskeyid=82322b94fs1c912&stwu=bfbf5&stwinside=1&stwurl=";
$lines = file($url);
print implode("", $lines);
```

We have had the odd occasion of URL's working with stwurl set, but not reliably
We went back and tried some which had succesfully retrieved thumbnails and couldn't get them to work.

**Error and fopen settings:**

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Fopen wrappers ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; Whether to allow the treatment of URLs (like http:// or ftp://) as files.
allow_url_fopen = On

; Whether to allow include/require to open URLs (like http:// or ftp://) as files.
allow_url_include = Off
```

which is one both machines. Error configuration:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL
```

and both successfully log to /tmp/php.log

Comment: Basic debugging: What is the output of this code -- `echo 'here 1'; $lines = file($url); echo 'here 2'; implode("", $lines); echo 'here 3';`

Comment: Hello Dan, all the echos are printing successfully. So, I'm assuming $lines is empty from the file(). Thanks for your reply - any other suggestions?

Comment: what does `var_dump($lines)` output?

Comment: what does `var_dump(error_reporting())` output, if placed right before `$lines = file($url)`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to access the URL from the command line of both machines (using curl or wget). It might be a network (or firewall) problem.

Comment: Hello - thanks for the reply. Just trying the URL with wget and it responds fine. So no networking issues.

Answer (score 0):

Is any of those parameters one-use-only? Try loading the same URL FIRST with the 2nd machine and then with the 1st.

Oh and also, even if just for simplicity's sake you could refactor the

```
$lines = file($url);
implode('',$lines);
```

thing with a file_get_contents($url) to further simplify the matter